# Como obtener una ubicación

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, razor

Hola que tal espero puedan ayudarme,

tengo esta consulta con linq

```
var Direccion = (from c in db.Colonia
                 join cp in db.CodPost on c.IdCodPostal equals cp.IdCodPostal
                 join m in db.Municipio on cp.IdMunicipio equals m.IdMunicipio
                 join e in db.Estado on m.IdEstado equals e.IdEstado
                 join p in db.Pais on e.IdPais equals p.IdPais
                 where(e.IdEstado == (UbicacionUsuario))
                 select new
                 {
                   label = c.NomColonia + ", " + cp.CodPostal + ", " + m.NomMunicipio,
                   valor = c.IdCCodPostal 
                 }).ToList();
```

La cual rellena un selectlist de esta manera

```
<select id="select2-basic-single" name="lugar" class="form-control">
   @foreach (var d in Direccion)
   {
       <option id="valuecolonia" value="@d.IdColonia">@d.label</option>
   }
</select>
```

El problema es que para mi condición where de mi consulta de linq necesito crear la variable "UbicacionUsuario" con la ubicación, ya que sin esa condición la consulta me carga TODO y el proceso se vuelve lento.